# Boostrap 4.5.2 Navbar Dropdown appearing in Wrong Location

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have created a navbar using Boostrap 4.5.2. In my navbar, I want to have a dropdown that goes with the tab "browse". My browse tab has three options associated with it. When I click on the "browse" tab; my dropdown menu appears with the correct content but it appears at the very start of the navbar. Any help on fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Below I have attached my navbar code and a gif of what happens.

```
     <div class="row d-flex align-items-center" id="top-bar">
        <!--Website title-->
        <div class="col-auto"><h1>My Website</h1></div>
        <!--nav bar-->
        <div class="col-auto">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="nav">
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./about.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="./advanced_search.html">Advanced Search</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                  <a
                    class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                    href="#"
                    id="navbarDropdown"
                    role="button"
                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    Browse
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Part01_PostList.php"
                      >Posts</a
                    >
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Part02_SinglePost.php?post_id=1"
                      >Images</a
                    >
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Part03_SingleImage.php?image_id=1"
                      >Users</a
                    >
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <!--Utility dropdown-->
        <div class="nav-dropdown mx-auto" id="utility-nav">
          <i class="fa fa-cog btn btn-secondary"  type="button" id="utility-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></i>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./favorites-list.php">Favorites List</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Register</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Search bar-->
        <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
        <form action="./Part04_Search.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="search-bar">
            <input
              class="form-control mr-sm-2"
              type="text"
              name="title-alt"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <button class="btn-primary" id="search-btn" type="submit">
              Search
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

https://i.gyazo.com/49fd1ebe460510762a683ab9aff1349f.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is over towards the left because in the list item, you’re using the class `nav-dropdown,` but that’s not a Bootstrap class. If you change it to `dropdown` (or `dropleft` or `dropright`), then the dropdown menu will be under the Browse button.

Was:
`<li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">`

Change to:
`<li class="nav-item dropdown">`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="row d-flex align-items-center" id="top-bar">
    <!--Website title-->
    <div class="col-auto">
        <h1>My Website</h1>
    </div>
    <!--nav bar-->
    <div class="col-auto">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="nav">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./about.php">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./advanced_search.html">Advanced Search</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Browse
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Part01_PostList.php">Posts</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Part02_SinglePost.php?post_id=1">Images</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Part03_SingleImage.php?image_id=1">Users</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--Utility dropdown-->
    <div class="nav-dropdown mx-auto" id="utility-nav">
        <i class="fa fa-cog btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="utility-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></i>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./favorites-list.php">Favorites List</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Account</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Register</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Search bar-->
    <div class="col-auto ml-auto">
        <form action="./Part04_Search.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="search-bar">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="title-alt" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
            <button class="btn-primary" id="search-btn" type="submit">
                Search
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```